# Azure Storage 403 Forbidden exception a 32-bit issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

We've spent quite some time to locate the reason for the following exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) 
   in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Core\\Executor\\Executor.cs:line 604
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.Create(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) 
   in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Blob\\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line 68
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) 
   in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Blob\\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line 233
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) 
   in c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\release_dotnet_master\\Lib\\ClassLibraryCommon\\Blob\\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line 196
...The rest is removed for clearity...
```

As a last resort we changed the App-service environment setting from 32-bit (seems to be default) to 64-bit and the problem was solved. No more forbidden exceptions.

We still don't know why 32-bit should cause the exception. Does anybody know why? Would be nice to know.

**Update**

Assemblies in our solution are compiled as .NET 4.6.1/Any CPU

**Some of the theories we have**

- Nuget/Azure incompatibilities (versioning)
- JIT-compiler 32-bit/64-bit differences
- Timing issues with 32-bit (authentication and server-clock)
- Other...

Comment: Did you login from portal and check if your keys are re-generated? check if you can access storage account with the same keys in your code

Comment: This is really interesting! Can you reproduce this error by switching back to 32-bit?

Comment: @ulugToprak: We tried the re-generate-keys fix as suggested by others for this exception. Unfortunately, that didn't solve our problem. Others also suggested a server-clock issue, which didn't seem to be the case here. We were surprised to find that switching from 32-bit to 64-bit in the hosting environment should solve the problem

Comment: @gauravMantri: Yes, it fails when we switch back to 32-bit

Comment: @gauravMantri: We started to experience 403-forbidden exceptions in the 32-bit environment around 1.th of April this year (2017)

Comment: Using IIS manager?

Comment: @UlugToprak: "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"

Comment: this is what used in the past [ISS manager for remote administration](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager) I remember having difficulty with 32-bit version. i think it was related to proxy issues and enabling 32-bit applications via application pool settings solved it for me thats why i asked if you were using iis manager. seems very similar to your issue.

Comment: @UlugToprak: They might be related. Are you hosting in IIS on a virtual machine? We are hosting our web-app as an Azure App Service. By default an Azure App Service seems to be configured as 32-bit and you manually (in Azure Cloud Portal) need to switch to 64-bit. Its probably the same application-pool thingy under the hood.

Comment: @Frode You can add all sorts to your IIS management console may that be Azure App services like web apps, mobile apps, API apps etc. its a remote administration tool. it makes tracing failed requests etc. very easy

Comment: was this issue resolved or do you still need help on it ?

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT, I'm not sure or fully remember the issue. If you should identify Azure Storage code that conflicts with Azure App Services running as 32-bit then yes please :)