# azure blob returns 403 forbidden with correct access key

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

My test site has after a deploy started to get 403 forbidden back when trying to access files from the azure blob storage.
This is only a problem on our test environment, the new release works just fine in production. Both production and test is hosted in azure, and both use their own azure blob storage.

I have tried regenerating the access keys for the blob storage, without any luck.
I can use the access keys locally and connect to the test blob storage and access the files just fine.
If i try to change the test environment to use the production blob storage, i still get the 403 forbidden error.

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server
> returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
> remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 677 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1
> cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in
> c:\Program Files
> (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
> 604 at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(StorageUri
> blobUri, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options,
> OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files
> (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobClient.cs:line
> 563 at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(String
> blobName, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options,
> OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files
> (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line
> 818 at ASP.XYZ in d:\XYZ.cshtml:line 27 Request Information
> RequestID:fc137321-0001-00ce-02d2-de5736000000 RequestDate:Tue, 06 Jun
> 2017 14:41:21 GMT StatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the
> request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed
> correctly including the signature.

It must be an issue on the azure app service that runs the test site. I just cannot see what it could be.

See gist here for some very simplified code https://gist.github.com/Skaanning/5cddf95a0d1ff210482d99a683e0be9c .

**Edit**
I have multiple other blob stores, but none of them work on the test site. They work fine on other environments though.

**I tried scaling it up and down, without any luck. But then i tried changing from 32 bit to 64 bit and now it works! I will keep the question open, in case someone can explain what on earth happened here**

Comment: Are the configurations the same for both storage accounts/containers? Specifically at the container level do they both have the same Access Policy? Also, what's in the "blob.storage" is it the key or the connection string?

Comment: blob.storage is a connection string from web.config. It has worked just fine until it suddenly didnt.
They both have the blob access policy

Answer (score 7):

> var img = container.GetBlobReference("someimage.png"); // this works just fine
>   var img2 = container.GetBlobReferenceFromServer("someimage.png"); // this throws a 403

The first line will work fine. The reason is that it will not send request to server when we execute GetBlobReference method. When executing GetBlobReferenceFromServer method, it will send a request to server to get the blob content. It will throw 404 not found exception if the blob can't be found in blob server.

> My test site has after a deploy started to get 403 forbidden back when trying to access files from the azure blob storage.

The 403 forbidden exception often caused by a wrong access key is used. Please print out the connection string which was used in your test environment.

```
Trace.Write(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("blob.storage"));
```

A Azure Storage connection string uses following format. Please make sure you have provided a right account name and key pair for the connection string. If you set account name1 and account key for account name2, it will cause the exception.

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[accountName];AccountKey=[accountKey];EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

Another thing would cause this issue is that the request to your storage server is rejected by your test server. Please check whether you have configured [Dynamic IP Security](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) in your web.config.

**Edit 2017/6/7 4:26 PM**

I suggest you take my upper suggestion. Please print out the connection string at runtime. If you set the connections string in both app setting in Azure portal and web.config. settings in Azure portal will override the settings in web.config.

Please also print out the current date time at runtime to check whether system time of your app instance is right. If the date or time of your system has been changed, 404 Forbidden also will happen.

The storage services ensure that a request is no older than 15 minutes by the time it reaches the service. This guards against certain security attacks, including replay attacks. When this check fails, the server returns response code 403 (Forbidden).

Reference: [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Authentication-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services#a-namesubheading1a-specifying-the-date-header)

**Edit 2017/6/7 5:55 PM**

Have you tried removing all the original files at your test server when deploying your release?

[image]

Comment: Hi. The connection string is correct. I can use them just fine from my local machine.  I have also tried regenerating the key and using the new one instead - without any luck.
We have no dynamicIpSecurity set, but we do have ipSecurity allowUnlisted=false that only allows a specific set of IPs. This has not changed in any release for a long long time though.

Comment: Which Azure Service did you use to host your Web Application? Azure Web App or Cloud Service or Azure VM?

Comment: Its an app service, type web app

Comment: The connection string is only set in web.config. I print it out and its the same as what i find in the blob access keys.  The time is in UTC and looks correct.

Comment: Have you tried removing all the original files at your test server when deploying your release?

Comment: Tried it, no luck :(

Comment: If the issue related to dedicate Azure web app instance, you could scale up your web app plan to a new tie. Then scale the web app plan back.  After that, your web app will run in a new instance.

Comment: I tried scaling it up and down, without any luck.
But then i tried changing from 32 bit to 64 bit and now it works!
I will keep the question open, in case someone can explain what on earth happened here

Comment: It seems a bug of web app. Here is a similar issue from this forum. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777425/azure-storage-403-forbidden-exception-a-32-bit-issue. I suggest you close this thread and submit this issue to Azure feedback site. Your issue will be seen by Azure production team.  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps

Comment: I had the same exact problem, switching from any cpu to x64 made it work.

Comment: If you're on .net core, the old Framework libraries don't work.  It *looks* like they do in code (no compile errors) but you'll get this error when trying to connect to blob storage.  Upgraded to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet and it's all good now.

Answer (score 6):

Review your server datetime. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error the only thing that fixed the error was by switching the platform to x64 from any cpu. What voodo is this?

I then changed back to "Any CPU" deleted all local file manually this time instead of using rebuild or clean from Visual Studio. Rebuilt from clean, I no longer get the 403.

Answer (score 2):

My servertime was wrong, somehow my application set the time back 1 hour 20 mins and that would result in a 403, I'm speculating that the authorization from azure blobstorage uses server time for its authentication.

At least setting the time back to correct worked for me.

Comment: Ran into this issue on my local machine when my PC clock was off over an hour.  After correcting the clock the 403 issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar issue:  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Fix: I have configured the access policy **readonly** on the azure portal.
I was using the readonly access policy to generate the SAS url in my c# code, as the was no readonly key configured the error was happening.

follow below fix:

[Azure storage container Access policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9omp.png)

[Azure storage container Access policy Set readonly/write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RgAL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the other one of the two access keys and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was - Change access level to Blob,not a container

Comment: Hi Serge and Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you take a look here on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), this way you can ensure the most people can take benefit from it!